# SQL database design: storing the type of a row

Tags: sql, schema

I am designing a database to contain a table `reference`, with a column `type` that is one of several predefined values (e.g., `book`, `movie`, `magazine`, etc.). I intend the range of possible values to expand over time (e.g. if I realize that I missed the `academic_paper` type, I want to be able to put that in).

The easiest solution would seem to be to simply store a string representing the type into the table. But this sounds like it would result in a lot of wasted space.

The other solution I thought of is creating a new table `reference_types`, which the `type` column references in its foreign key. This seems to have the added benefit of ensuring valid foreign keys (so that I won't accidentally mistype a "magzine" somewhere in my code), possible allow for faster queries for all media of a certain type (since integer comparisons should be much faster than string comparisons), but also slow my application down a bit as joins would be required whenever I need the reference type, and probably complicate logic because of those extra joins.

What are your thoughts on schema design for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution is the correct one.  Create a secondary table to store your reference types and link them using a foreign key.

For further reading on this subject the search term you'd want to use is 'database normalisation'.

Answer (score 1):

Create the reference_types table. And in your references table use integer and also add a reference_type_name field.

You can query the references table to get the integer key and print its name when needed without performing a join to the other table, and still use that table to perfom other operations, just keep both tables with equal type names.

I know it sonds redundant, but it's really the fastest way to do a simple query by int key and have it all together.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you will want to add some other information to reference types, then use the second approach. If not, use the first one because it's faster and the information stored is only a string (you can always select unique to retrieve your types). Read this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for more info.